# Jenkins: connect to a slave via SSH with a different user name

Tags: ssh, jenkins

I have a master running with user XXX on a machine M1. I want to run a slave on machine M2 with user YYY.

I have a private-public key in place between the two machines, so that I can do:

```
[XXX@M1]$ ssh YYY@M2
```

And I am connected.

In Jenkins, I created credentials for username M2 and selected the option *From the Jenkins master ~/.ssh*. But when I try to connect it fails:

```
[04/18/13 14:58:11] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to M2:22.
ERROR: Failed to authenticate as YYY with credential=c2cdc4dd-cb39-4f15-8329-033933ad5621
java.io.IOException: Publickey authentication failed.

[04/18/13 14:58:11] [SSH] Authentication failed.
hudson.AbortException: Authentication failed.
```

Surprisingly, if I use the option *Enter directly* and copy paste the private key from `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, then it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of preference is: id_rsa, id_dsa, identity

So it will take ~/.ssh/id_rsa if that is present and only fall back to ~/.ssh/id_dsa if the id_rsa is missing.

Where you have multiple keys and you need to specify explicitly one key, the recommendation is to either specify the path to the file or use copy & paste